# how do i restrict numericupdown control to accept only integers

Tags: .net, integer, numericupdown

I have a windows numericupdown control. I want to restrict it so that user can only enter integers in it. How do I do that? At present a user can enter a decimal number as well.
Thanks
PS I am using .net

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did a little experimenting and found this workaround:

```
    private void numericUpDown1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 57)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

This way you will not be able to type thousand separators either but you could add that by first finding out what the thousand separator is and allowing that too.

Comment: You might want to allow backspace - check for (e.KeyChar != 8) above.

Comment: @amolbk - yes and other keys (arrows, home, end, Ctrl-C,V and X) might be usefull too.

Comment: Copy and paste may still be problematic

Comment: It is easy to accept Copy. Before pasting it might be needed to check whether or not the clipboard contains valid data that can/should be displlayed

Comment: Is not a bad answer but at the present day is better use DecimalPlaces = 0

Answer (score 9):

Set the [`DecimalPlaces`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.decimalplaces(v=vs.110).aspx) property to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Set `DecimalPlaces = 0`:

```
public class IntegerUpDown : NumericUpDown
   {
      public IntegerUpDown(): base() 
      {
         DecimalPlaces = 0;
      }

      protected override void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object source, EventArgs e) 
      {
         base.OnTextBoxTextChanged( source, e);
         ValidateEditText();
      }
   }
```

See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.decimalplaces

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the AjaxControlToolkit, you can just combine the FilteredTextBoxExtender with the NumericUpDownExtender:

```
<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBoxNums" FilterType="Numbers">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
<asp:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericUpDownExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBoxNums" Width="10">
</asp:NumericUpDownExtender>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNums" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Oops I just noticed you're using Windows Forms and not Web Forms

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to **DevExpress controls**, you should use a [SpinEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsSpinEdittopic) control and set its `Properties.IsFloatValue` to *false*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to not allow the typing of the number decimal separator on the current system:

```
private void NumericUpDown_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Do not accept the default decimal separator
    char sep = Convert.ToChar(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
    if (e.KeyChar == sep)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Everything else works (Backspace, etc.)