# How do I style an Avalonia NumericUpDown control integer-only?

Tags: numericupdown, avalonia

Every time I click the Up or Down button of an Avalonia `NumericUpDown` control a period with a zero gets added to the value, i.e. it increases as 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 etc. instead of 2, 3, 4 (which would be the desired behaviour).

The decimal point and the zero only disappear as soon as the application window loses focus and appear again once I click decrease/increase again.

How do I possibly change this?

[An answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45633789/274627) suggests setting the `DecimalPlaces` property to zero but the Avalonia implementation of the control appears lacking this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the incrementation level, it should be automatic.

```xml
<NumericUpDown Increment="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Increment` property cannot prevent user from entering the fractional part of a number from keyboard =(

If you want allow the user to enter only integers, use this combination of properties:

```
<NumericUpDown FormatString="N0"
               ParsingNumberStyle="Integer" />
```

`ParsingNumberStyle` is for blocking user to enter decimal point, and `FormatString` is for displaying value without fractional part while editing from keyboard.